# trigger to update value from one table to other

Tags: oracle11g

I'm trying to create a trigger to get value of `plan_id` from `db` table which has occured more than 3 times and then update value of `amount` regarding that `plan_id` in `preplan` or `postplan` tables(wherever plan_id belongs to).

Schema for my tables are like this:

`db table:`

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PLAN_ID                                   NOT NULL NUMBER
 CONNECTION_ID                             NOT NULL NUMBER
```

`preplan:`

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PLAN_ID                                   NOT NULL NUMBER
 AMOUNT                                             NUMBER
```

`postplan:`

```
     Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PLAN_ID                                   NOT NULL NUMBER
 AMOUNT                                             NUMBER
```

I have written following trigger for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  TRIGGER plan_discount_trigger

AFTER INSERT
   ON db FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

   l_planid  number(5);
   l_amount  number(5);

BEGIN

 SELECT plan_id from db into l_planid group by plan_id having count(:NEW.plan_id)>3;
    IF (l_planid>0 and l_planid<6) THEN
        select amount into l_amount from preplan;
        update preplan SET prepaid.amount = l_amount - (l_amount * 0.1);

    ELSIF (l_planid>9 and l_planid<16) THEN
        select amount into l_amount from postplan;
        update postplan SET postpaid.amount = l_amount - (l_amount * 0.1);
  ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line("invalid plan!");

    end IF;
end;
```

its giving error:

```
8/2      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
8/25     PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Just explain me what the error is and how to solve it???

Comment: Try single quotes instead of double quotes around "invalid plan!" and count(plan_id)>3 instead of count(:NEW.plan_id)>3

Comment: @ramana Its giving same error!!

Comment: "SELECT plan_id from db into l_planid"  should be, "SELECT plan_id into l_planid from db"

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be changed

```
 SELECT plan_id from db into l_planid group by plan_id having count(:NEW.plan_id)>3;
```

to

```
SELECT plan_id into l_planid from db  group by plan_id having count(plan_id)>3;
```